# When does Apple iOS releases memory

Tags: iphone, ios4

I was wondering when does iOS releases resources allocated to an app. For example, let's say I have an app like Angry Birds or something and after playing for some time I close it and kill it from the "task manager" (double click home). When will the resources allocated to the app be released?

Do you have any resources on the subject?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while double click home and close the angry bird , the ios will send kill message to angry bird, so after that ios will reclaim its memory to reuse.after killing the app the memory for that app will also be freed.

u may think of where is the global autorelease pool for app.

take a look at the main function which starts with autorelease pool.

Comment: This is clear enough! But what happens to the allocated memory, during the time that the app stays "on the background"? I mean, does iOS persists a "state of the app" and frees memory making it available for the foreground app, or does it keep this memory allocated to the app even if in background mode?

Comment: it will remain in Ram when it is in background.but no. of apps is limit.while u kill the app ios will claim its memory to reuse.

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [dealloc](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

> Note that when an **application terminates**, objects may not be sent a
>   dealloc message since the **process’s memory is automatically cleared on
>   exit**—it is more efficient simply to allow the operating system to
>   clean up resources than to invoke all the memory management methods.

If we read between the lines, we must make out that all memory is quickly cleaned up when an application terminates(without even calling memory management methods in the app)..

Answer (score 0):

iOS will release memory when the time is right :-)

When it needs memory for some app in foreground it will release the memory of apps in the background. When you develop an app you can choose if your app can run in the background or not. If you set it as "no" then app will release resources when you close it with home.